# Converting string to int java

Tags: java, string, int

```
package kappa;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kappa {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Who are you ?");
        String Name;
        Name = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("So you are " + Name);

       String any;
       System.out.println("Press any to continue");
       any = scanner.next();

      int age;
       System.out.println("Enter you age : " );
        age = Integer.parseInt();

       if(age > 18){
       System.out.println(Name + " is older than 18");

       }
       if (age < 18){
       System.out.println(Name + " is younger than 18");
       }
       }


    }
```

// i dont how to convert string to int and i know this is an easy problem but im just new to java language so any help will be really helpful.

Comment: google before post here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int i = Integer.parseInt(stringVariable);` But after looking at your code I found some issues and suggestions:

1. `age = Integer.parseInt(); // Not valid.`

if you want to achieve that then you need to use `int age = scanner.nextInt();`

2. You should ideally use variable name starting with small case  and then go for camelcase. Example : `String name, String firstName`, etc.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change `age = Integer.parseInt();` to `age = scanner.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

You may go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Other than that you can **scanner.nextInt();** but before taking next int you have use **scanner.next()** to emty the scanner .As scanner has not been read completely yet.Then again use **scanner.nextInt()** to get new value.

Also need try catch for **scanner.nextInt()** as this may throw error in case of int not found.